# Why is std::cout adding return or newlines to my output?

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

Using `stringstream` to extract words from a sentence.

There is a newline being added for each word, and I can't see why; can you?  Thx for your help. Keith :^)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int wordCount(9);
    std::vector<std::string> v(wordCount);
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
    std::string tStr;
    std::string myStr = "the quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dogs";
    std::stringstream ss(myStr);
    std::cout << "Sentence broken into vector:" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<wordCount; ++i) {
        ss >> tStr;
        v.push_back(tStr);
    }
    for (it=v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation, run, and output. Note extra newlines.

```
pickledEgg $ g++ -std=c++11 -g -Og -o io2 io2.cpp
pickledEgg $ ./io2
Sentence broken into vector:









the
quick
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
brown
dogs
```

Comment: This would be an excellent time to use a debugger.

Comment: You're not using `std::cin` anywhere in that code...

Comment: you created the vector with 9 empty strings and then you pushed the other strings onto the end... the output exactly matches that

Comment: @qxz sorry fixed. This is a little driver snippet to showcase the problem. The real program uses ``std::cin``

Comment: Ah, ok. It's good that you created a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, but it's also good to leave out extraneous information (although some context is usually useful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you created your vector with this line `std::vector<std::string> v(wordCount);` you created `wordCount` empty entries. When you called `push_back` to add your words, you appended your words at the end of your vector. When you iterated over your vector, you first printed the empty entries with new lines, then your good data.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Good eye; long day for me.

Comment: @kmiklas It was fresh in my memory because of another question, else I'd have probably missed it.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly simple:

```
//std::vector<std::string> v(wordCount);
std::vector<std::string> v;
```

I think you wanted to use `std::vector::reserve`.

> The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular
>   pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a
>   vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an
>   element of an array.
>   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Because `std::vector::push_back` appends value into the vector, causing a change of it's size. If you deal with a vector of large enough size, you should consider using `std::vector::reserve`.

You can see the difference in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve.

Comment: It was too late ;)

Comment: You can expand on the answer and explain what's happening exactly, so it's never too late.